label radio input with data attribute not working on Bootstrap 4 Carousel
I use Bootstrap 4 Carousel to switch images on a gallery when click on thumbs.
Works fine.
But I want also to switch the large image version when click on radio button using data attribute from Carousel. That is working, but the radio button get no checked status, only without the data attributes.
Is there a conflict witj Carousel Bootstrap jquery/javascript?
Has anyone an idea?
<input type="radio" name="artwork_choice" class="custom-control-input frame-input-element var_frame" id="unframed" value="unframed">
<label data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="radiolabel w-75 mt-1" for="unframed">
unframed
</label>

<input type="radio" name="artwork_choice" class="custom-control-input frame-input-element var_frame" id="framed" value="framed">
<label data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="radiolabel w-75 mt-1" for="framed">
framed
</label>

